# Best way to restart TimerTask in Service

Tags: android, service, restart, timertask

i would like to restart my TimerTask in my Service when i changed the refresh time in the config Activity.

The config Activity changes the public static long UPDATE_INTERVAL

Have you some ideas for me?

```
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {

    // init the service here
    try {
        if (prefs.getString("oauth_token_secret", null) != null) {
            _startService();
        }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

}

private void _startService() {

    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(
         new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {

            //doing things

        }
         }, 0, UPDATE_INTERVAL);

}
```

Thanks so far.
Stefan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "The config Activity changes the public static long UPDATE_INTERVAL", but you can update the interval timing in your run code and it will take effect the next time the TimerTask is run. Or if your Activity is in a seperate class you can create a setter for UPDATE_INTERVAL and when an action is triggered in the Activity you set the timing interval that way.

Comment: i tried this, but it only takes the value of UPDATE_INTERVAL that was set on the first time =/

Comment: Instead of using scheduleAtFixedRate() you should just use schedule(), and call the function recursively so that it will create a new timer each iteration with the updated interval.